# React handle autocomplete waiting for some time to load dynamic data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an AutoComplete component and by default it has no data to display. When a user types something it will load data dynamically. But I want this to be done when user stops typing, not each time enters something quickly. So I wait for 1500 miliseconds and then check if string has changed or not. But the code doesn't work the way I expected.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const [searchStr, setSearchStr] = useState(null);

function handleChange(event) {
    const str = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

    if (str.length < 2) return;

    setSearchStr(str);

    setTimeout(() => {
      // str never equals searchStr
      console.log(str, searchStr)
      if(str === searchStr) {
         dispatch(doSearch(searchStr));
      }
    }, 1500);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems in your code.

1- `setState` is run asynchronously so `setSearchStr` doesn't instantly change the value of `searchStr`

2- Each time the input changes, a new `setTimeout` is created so after 1500ms from the first character typing, it will lose its effect. The thing you're going to do is called `debouncing`. The solution is to clear the previous `setTimeout`s before creating a new one:

```js
let timer; // =========> HERE

function MyComponent() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [searchStr, setSearchStr] = useState(null);

  function handleChange(event) {
    const str = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

    if (str.length < 2) return;

    setSearchStr(str);

    clearTimeout(timer); // =========> HERE

    timer = setTimeout(() => {
       dispatch(doSearch(str));
    }, 1500);
  }
}
```

If you insist on saving the search value in a stateful variable, you can use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

```js
let timer; // =========> HERE

function MyComponent() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [searchStr, setSearchStr] = useState(null);

  function handleChange(event) {
    const str = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

    setSearchStr(str);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchStr.length < 2) return;

    clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(() => {
       dispatch(doSearch(searchStr));
    }, 1500);
  }, [searchStr])
}
```